# Python: Letter repair using OpenCV for text recognition

Tags: python, opencv

I am trying to repair image contains letters each letter split into two halves from the middle.

original Image

[image]

After Applying the following code:

```
gray = cv2.cvtColor(cropped_bot, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

new_img = ((gray >= 230)*255).astype('uint8')    

bottom_image =  255-new_img
```

I get this Image 
[image]

My Problem is to fix the line that split the letters into two part.

I have tried `adaptiveThreshold`

```
cv2.adaptiveThreshold(gray, 255, cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C, cv2.THRESH_BINARY, 15, 2)
```

But it doesn't help. How I can solve this

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to identify incomplete rectangles in openCV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44295099/how-to-identify-incomplete-rectangles-in-opencv)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are a few steps you can follow:

- Perform Otsu threshold on the gray scale image
- Apply morphological *close* operation with a kernel

**Code :**

```
ret, thresh1 = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY | cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
cv2.imshow('thresh1', thresh1)
```

[image]

```
k = np.array([[1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1]], np.uint8)
closing = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh1, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, k)
cv2.imshow(closing, closing)
```

[image]

### UPDATE:

```
k1 = np.ones((3, 3), np.uint8)
erosion = cv2.erode(closing, k1, iterations = 1)
cv2.imshow(erosion, erosion)
```

[image]

Comment: **Perfect** (Y)

Comment: I have a small problem. a big line appears when I convert black and white as here https://ibb.co/cgx7ed

Comment: @ahmedosama How are you getting this image?

Comment: `closing =  255-closing`

Comment: @ahmedosama I did `closing = 255-closing` but I got something different. Check the result I got in the answer.

Comment: sorry. i found the reason for this line `closing =cv2.adaptiveThreshold(closing , 255, cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C, cv2.THRESH_BINARY, 15, 2)`

Comment: @ahmedosama Hope you've got the result you expected

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173270/discussion-between-ahmed-osama-and-jeru-luke).