# Split image horizontally with python based on dark center line

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, opencv

Goal is to horizontally split an image (double newspaper page) in python based on a vertical centerline that is darker than other areas around.

Example image:

[image]

Had some luck using opencv (`cv2`) for the initial crop and rotation of the double page from a black background using `cv2.Canny`, and then sorting the contours based on `cv2.contourArea`.

But, now I'm just interested in finding a center line and then splitting the image into two separate images.  Using `cv2.Canny` again I see that it's able to identify that centerline, but not sure how to identify that long, vertical line and use that to split the image:

[image]

End goal would be two images like the following:

[image]
[image]

Any suggestions would be most welcome.

Comment: You can try with HoughTransform. Also, if you know the line is vertical you could only compute horizontal gradient instead of canny.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, run a horizontal gradient so you only accentuate vertical edges. You can calculate a horizontal gradient with these coefficients:

```
-1   0   1
-2   0   2
-1   0   1
```

Then compute the sum of the vertical columns, you can use `np.sum(array,axis=0)` and you will get this:

[image]

I have re-shaped it for ease of viewing - it is actually only 1 pixel tall. Hopefully you can see the bright white line in the middle which you can find with Numpy `argmax()`. It will also be better when you just do a horizontal gradient because at the moment I am using the purple and yellow image with vertical and horizontal edges enhanced.

Note that the inspiration for this approach is that you said you *"want to identify that long, vertical centerline"* and the rationale is that a long line of white pixels will add up to a large sum. Note that I have assumed your image is de-skewed (since you said the line is vertical) and this method may not work so well on skew images where *"vertical"* line will be spread across several columns.

Comment: This is a very interesting approach. Do you happen to have any code showing how one might use it in practice?

Comment: @NickK9 There's an example here https://stackoverflow.com/a/56808568/2836621 and another here https://stackoverflow.com/a/52096044/2836621